# Can you attach a USB drive to the motherboard with SATA?

Tags: usb, sata, usb-to-sata

I want to attach a USB Drive to my motherboard with SATA. It is a liveUSB with Ubuntu Linux installed, but USB 2.0 is slow... So is there some kind of <strike>USB to SATA</strike> SATA (PC side interface) to USB (device side interface)  cable?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I know about `eSATAp` but I don't think I have a port for that. I want to attach my USB to the port where the HDD is attached.

Comment: *"So is there some kind of USB to SATA cable?"* -- No.  BTW your question is based on a flawed premise.  Attaching *"a USB drive to the motherboard with SATA"* is not going to make the USB drive transfer any faster..

Comment: @sawdust why so? SATA ports are supposed to be faster than USB 2.0, and if the drive has greater speed than USB 2.0, it should make the drive run faster...

Comment: You want to add an adapter, a *"USB to SATA cable"*.  How are you eliminating the USB interface?

Comment: What I am saying is, the device side port (USB) should only be used as a connector, just because I cannot break it off and put in SATA...

Comment: @sawdust The PC side interface will be SATA like it is in hard drives. The only difference will be that the device side interface will have to be USB (it is SATA in hard drives) because it is a USB drive.

Comment: Your understanding of computer hardware is deficient. The connector is just what you see of the interface.  The electrical signals are different/incompatible between USB and SATA.  The protocols are different/incompatible between USB and SATA.. You haven't answered the question: How are you eliminating the USB interface?

Comment: @sawdust Precisely, that is why adapters exist.

Comment: Ok, so is there any way I can make a liveUSB run faster?

Comment: @NabeelOmer: That is NOT why adapters exist. You can make a LiveUSB run faster by running it from a faster drive.

Comment: @NabeelOmer: Your external drive contains a SATA (or if older, IDE), drive inside an enclosure.  The enclosure contains an interface to convert that to USB.  If you leave the drive in the enclosure, anything you use to connect it to the motherboard will go through, and be limited by, the enclosure's USB interface.  The only way to remove USB (and its limitations), from the picture is to take the drive out of the enclosure.  If it is a SATA drive, you can connect it to your motherboard.  If it's an IDE drive, you could add an IDE interface on a PCI card.

Comment: Even with a SATA adapter, the data still pass through the USB interface which make the bandwidth low. It is like your Ethernet 1Gbit/s connected to your PC and your ISP router… it is not because this interface is fast that you can download file from Internet at 1Gbit/s. The slower interface in the chain set the speed of the whole data path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your motherboard has a 4-pin USB internal header, you can get an eSATAp adaptor for it.

Other than that, I cannot find a SATA->USB adaptor only USB->SATA.

Of course, you could remove the drive from it's USB housing and put it in a housing with a SATA connection exposed.

Alternatively, you could mount it internally if you have room. It wouldn't be portable then of course.

Comment: What do you mean `mount it internally`? Do you mean to attach it to the port directly on the motherboard?

Comment: What kind of PC are we talking about here? I assumed a desktop since you mentioned the mobo? A desktop PC will often have space for putting >1 drive inside the case. Then you can directly wire it with SATA.

Comment: Yes, i am talking about a desktop.