# On Mounting a thumb drive as an internal disk using a sata adapter

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, sata, adapter

My question is similar [another](https://superuser.com/q/929422/109803) one but I'm trying to do something realistic.

#### Background

Windows will not let you install the OS to a thumbdrive as it passes a flag when you plug it in that its a removable drive.

#### Problem

I'm trying to disguise a thumb drive (128gb) as in internal disk-drive so I can install windows to it.

#### Attempts

I was thinking that an approach I could use was mount the USB on Windows using a M-sata to F-USB adapter. I have an *USB 3.0 & eSATA to SATA Hard Drive Docking Station* that I could plug the adapter into.

What would you do? I was unable to find any USB-F -> M-SATA adapters, or other suggestions online. Maybe I could daisy chain something else together.

Comment: 128gb ssd is maybe 40$; most adapters are 25$; do adapters even exist that take USB and convert it to SATA? Most do the opposite.

Comment: Even if you could do this, trying to run windows on a thumbdrive would be a nightmare!  The USB interface and performance characteristics of a thumbdrive are not good enough to cope with trying to run a windows O/S on it.  It would be very laggy and slow at best.  Maybe like trying to run it from CD-ROM!  I did find this however:  http://www.addonics.com/products/adsau31r.php

Comment: yeah I know the performance would be bad. I only need this contraption to install the os, once its installed it can be run directly off the USB from any 3.0 port. Your link might work for me. Thanks